# Creating dynamic variable in JavaScript for URLs

Tags: javascript, html, url

My current variable 'theurl' has a given static URL. I'd like to pass through URLs through the variable. The main issue is that the URL that i want are created through entering a value on a separate website. Is there an way of retrieving the URL this way or is it completely terrible?

The website i want to retrieve the produced URL from is https://cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/ri1Q7.html#

from there i enter the code 'A0033H' in the search field next to the drop down menu with 'kurs/program' (in swedish) selected.

At the moment I've checked out the passing value between two html pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var HttpClient = function () {
            this.get = function (aUrl, aCallback) {
                var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                        aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
                anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
                anHttpRequest.send(null);
            }
        }



        var theurl = 'https://cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/ri166XQ2505Z5YQv250132Z6yQY820653YX5Y3gQ3076757.json';
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.get(theurl, function (response) {
            var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
            //alert(response);

            var test = JSON.stringify(response);

            var test2 = test.replace(/,/g, "  ");
            var test3 = test2.replace(/}/g, " ");
            var test4 = test3.replace(/{/g, " ");
            var test5 = test4.replace(/"/g, " ");
            var test6 = test5.replace(/ /g, " ");
            var test7 = test6.replace(/\\/g, " ");
            var test8 = test7.replace(/ \ /g, " ");
            var test9 = test8.replace(/\ /g, " ");
            var test10 = test9.replace(/]/g, " ");
            var test11 = test10.replace(/\[/g, " ");
            var test12 = test11.replace(/"  "/g, '');


            //alert(test12);

            // this is the string variable
            var wordLength = test12.length; // we use the length method to store the length of the word string in a variable

            document.write('<table>');
            document.write('<tr><th>Lektioner</th></tr>');



            for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {

                var indexNr = test12.indexOf('id', i += 100);
                var indexNr2 = test12.indexOf('id', i += 200);
                //alert(indexNr);
                //alert(indexNr2);

                var substring = test12.substring(indexNr, indexNr2);
                // alert(substring);
                var j = 200;
                var indexNr4 = test12.indexOf('columns', j += 110);
                var indexNr3 = test12.indexOf('id', j += 110);
                var substring2 = test12.substring(indexNr4, indexNr3);

                document.write('<tr><td>' + substring + '</td></tr>');
            }
            document.write('</table>');
        });
    </script>
```

The produced result gives me the JSON format structured in a table as strings.

I know this is severe spaghetti code, but I'm just wondering if the retrieval of the URL is possible?

Comment: I don't understand when you mean "retrieval of the url" what url are you talking about?

Comment: I want to get a URL produced from the website https://cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/ri1Q7.html#. The website produces the URL when you enter a given course code. The URL is the same with the given course code - It doesn't change. 

It feels like a dumb work around but if you know anyway of simplifying the process im all ears

Comment: So you're trying to find a way to generate the url without manually going to `cloud.timeedit.net/ltu/web/schedule1/ri1Q7.html#` and typing in the password?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Ok, it would seem like it's possible.

Comment: After working on it a bit, they really tried their best to make the code very complicated. But it is in fact possible. They're just doing a good job at hiding it. I'll keep looking at it

Comment: Thanks for all the time youre spending on this! Even if it wouldnt produce any results